# Variable not updating in unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine, redux

I am working on a unit test, and I want to test that a value in a redux store is updated accordingly to my instructions.

My `module reducer` unit test contains multiple test suites, some are updating the state, some are not and I don't know why... So I come here after a day of test and research to see if someone may know the reason of my error. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Here is a portion of my module reducer code:

```
export function createModuleReducer() {
  return function moduleReducer(state: PageModules = INITIAL_STATE,
    action): PageModules {
      if (!action.meta || !action.meta.status) {
        return state;
      }
      switch (action.type) {
        case INITIALIZE:

        case CREATE_SIGNATURES_ARRAY:
          return tassign(state, {signatures: action.payload['document']});
```

Here is a portion of my module reducer spec code:

```
const baseState = {
  signatures: []
};
let state;
…
describe('Reducer', () => {
  …
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    …
    MockNgRedux.reset();
    state = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(baseState));
  }));

  it('should call CREATE_SIGNATURES_ARRAY reducer', async(() => {
    const actionCreateSignature = {
      type: CREATE_SIGNATURES_ARRAY,
      meta: { status: 'create_signature'},
      payload: { 'document': … }
    };
    createModuleReducer()(state, actionCreateSignature);
    mockNgRedux.dispatch(actionCreateSignature);
    expect(state.signatures).toEqual(…)
  }));
}
```

Using console.log, I know that the `module reducer` updates the store accordingly, but the value in the spec does not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reducers are supposed to be the easiest part to test, as they are pure functions.
Depending on how you implement your reducer, you probably don't need TestBed.
You also probably don't need MockNgRedux. I only use it in tests of components that use @select.

The state you pass in to the reducer should only be the fragment that the reducer is responsible for, in this case is it the signatures property? So perhaps your test call should be

```
createModuleReducer()(state.signatures, actionCreateSignature);
```

I'd also suggest putting a `console.log(state)` before your expect, to see how the reducer is treating it.

To give further advice, would need to know more about createModuleReducer() method.
Also, `mockNgRedux.dispatch()` doesn't look right. All the calls I've seen are static on **M**ockNgRedux (the class).

Comment: I updated my answer with the createModuleReducer function, which is a function containing a switch!

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed, thanks to the suggestion of Richard Matsen and redux documentation about testing reducers!

I test the createModuleReducer directly now:

```
expect(createModuleReducer()(state, actionCreateSignature).signatures).toEqual(…)
```